# SQL search for minimum values related to a table of duplicates

Tags: sql

I have a SQL View that pumps out the following table, two columns

```
Column 1   Column 2
ID         Value
1          10
1          12
1          15
2          3
2          6
```

I'd like to search for where record 1 returns it's minimum value (10) and record 2 returns it's minimum value (3)

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT 
    id
  , MIN(value)
FROM yourview
GROUP BY id
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like:

```
select [id], min([value]), max([value]) 
from viewname 
group by id
order by id
```

The square brackets are SQL Server syntax to sidestep keywords;  your database syntax may differ.  What database are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You could use Row_Number() OVER ().

```
; WITH cte AS (
    SELECT id1 = 1, value = 10 UNION ALL
    SELECT id1 = 1, value = 12 UNION ALL
    SELECT id1 = 1, value = 15 UNION ALL
    SELECT id1 = 2, value = 3 UNION ALL
    SELECT id1 = 2, value = 6
)
SELECT z.id1, z.value
FROM (
    SELECT id1, value,  ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY id1 ORDER BY value ASC ) AS rn 
    FROM cte
) z
WHERE z.rn = 1
```

Returns:

```
id1 value
1   10
2   3
```

Comment: Depending on how complex the rest of your data is, the min(value) would be a better way to go.